# Java Encryption & Decryption in my Spring Boot app

Tags: spring, jpa, encryption, spring-security, postgresql-9.3

I have a Sprint-Boot application that uses H2 (test) and Postgres(production).  I have a need to keep the customer data secure.  I also need to be able to search the database (using Spring-Data-JPA with Hibernate) and use that data, so that seems like I need a sort of encryption.  I see there are AttributeConverters, Jayst, and Spring Security has an interface TextEncryptor that appears to be suitable for encrypting and decrypting. I thought Spring might have this built into their Data-JPA/Security projects but I haven't found it yet. I do use BCryptPasswordEncoder for my password security.

However, I am not sure of a great way to encrypt /store /search/ decrypt data with Java/Spring/Hibernate.  My first thought is that if it's encrypted you can't search it.  I thought perhaps I should have the database handle the encryption, but I read articles advocating against that.

Can anyone suggest a very secure solution?

Comment: Just don't give everyone the username/password for the database... Also you would need 2 way encryption/decryption which isn't really secure it is basically just a layer of indirection.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I use database level encryption and just keep the credentials encrypted with something like Jayst ?

Comment: No. Encrypting data in the database is only a level of indirection. If you want to secure things you need a one way algorithm but for database nformation that needs to be shown on screen that isn't really an option. Are you sure you really want to encrypt everything in the database, why would that be needed.

Comment: I only need to secure customer information such as SSN, address, financial/health records, and contact information.  I currently encrypt the SSN but that means I can't search or use it elsewhere (submitting information to third parties, etc.).   I should say my ultimate goal is HIPAA/PCI compliance

Comment: Don't know those compliance rules. However encrypting data doesn't look needed but you need to control access quite strictly (from a first glance). Encrypt the connection etc. encrypting data will only slow down things and as mentioned (imho) adds nothing as you will need to have 2 way encryption.

Comment: So if I encrypt the communication channels (SSL to/from client, to/from database) the data should be reasonably secure?  I only use the data in the database from my application, but in your opinion, does encrypting the database or disk help?  Thank you again for your time, btw, this is a complicated topic and I haven't found a great guide on creating really secure web applications.